# How to ignore field repr in pydantic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic, python-attrs

When I want to ignore some fields using attr library, I can use `repr=False` option.
But I cloud't find a similar option in pydantic

Please see example code

```py
import typing
import attr

from pydantic import BaseModel


@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class AttrTemp:
    foo: typing.Any
    boo: typing.Any = attr.ib(repr=False)


class Temp(BaseModel):
    foo: typing.Any
    boo: typing.Any  # I don't want to print

    class Config:
        frozen = True


a = Temp(
    foo="test",
    boo="test",
)
b = AttrTemp(foo="test", boo="test")
print(a)  # foo='test' boo='test'
print(b)  # AttrTemp(foo='test')
```

However, it does not mean that there are no options at all, I can use the syntax `print(a.dict(exclude={"boo"}))`

Doesn't pydantic have an option like `repr=False`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this feature has been [requested](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1831) and [also](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/pull/2593) [implemented](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/5ccbdcb/pydantic/fields.py#L251) not long ago.

However, it seems like it hasn't made it into the [latest release](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/v1.8.2/pydantic/fields.py#L176) yet.

I see two options how to enable the feature anyway:

**1. Use the workaround provided in the [feature request](https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/issues/1831#issuecomment-803845310)**

Define a helper class:

```py
import typing
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class ReducedRepresentation:
    def __repr_args__(self: BaseModel) -> "ReprArgs":
        return [
            (key, value)
            for key, value in self.__dict__.items()
            if self.__fields__[key].field_info.extra.get("repr", True)
        ]
```

and use it in your `Model` definition:

```py
class Temp(ReducedRepresentation, BaseModel):
    foo: typing.Any
    boo: typing.Any = Field(..., repr=False)

    class Config:
        frozen = True

a = Temp(
    foo="test",
    boo="test",
)
print(a) 
# foo='test'
```

**2. `pip install` the latest `master`**

I would suggest doing this in a virtual environment. This is what worked for me:

Uninstall the existing version:

```
$ pip uninstall pydantic
...
```

Install latest `master`:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic.git@master
...
```

After that the `repr` argument should work out of the box:

```py
import typing
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class Temp(BaseModel):
    foo: typing.Any
    boo: typing.Any = Field(..., repr=False)

    class Config:
        frozen = True

a = Temp(
    foo="test",
    boo="test",
)
print(a) 
# foo='test'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is now implemented:

```py
import typing

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.typing import Annotated

class Temp(BaseModel):
    foo: typing.Any
    boo: Annotated[typing.Any, Field(repr=False)]
```

see: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/fields/#field-representation